# Getting wrong data from DB when joining MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to get some data from database but when I join each (either episodes table or user_credits or any of the example below) data gets crazy high and not correct or it runs so long and doesn't give any data, but separately written it is correct. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.email,
    COUNT(episodes.id) AS count_episodes,
    SUM(user_credits.credits) AS sum_coins
FROM
    users
        LEFT JOIN
    episodes ON users.id = episodes.client_user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    user_credits ON users.id = user_credits.user_id
WHERE
    users.gender = 'male'
        AND users.active = 1
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY sum_coins DESC;
```

Comment: I don't quite agree with the close as duplicate, at least not with that question. The problem here is that two joins generate multiple values. If there was only one join it would be OK. @hecc12 Try using subqueries rather than joins here.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired outcome as text to the question or to a fiddle.